# ASP.NET MVC 5. Ошибка маршрутизации при POST запросе

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Доброго времени суток.
Делаю сайт на ASP.NET MVC 5.
Во View есть кнопочка (форма)

```
       @using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <div class="pull-right">
                @Html.HiddenFor(b=> b.Id)
                @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Добавить в корзину"/>
            </div>
        }
```

Соответственно генерирует POST запрос контроллеру Cart, методу AddToCart.
проблема в том что при нажатии на кнопку возникает ошибка маршрутизации и не вызывается метод AddToCart.
ОШИБКА:"The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value, which is required. "

Настройки маршрутизации

```
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // URL:"/" - Выводит первую страницу списка товаров всех категорий
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: null,
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Books", action = "List", page = 1, genre = (string)null }
           );

        //URL: "/PageX" - Выводит страницу X, отображая товары всех категорий
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: null,
            url: "Page{page}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Books", action = "List", genre = (string)null },
            constraints: new { page = @"\d+" }
            );

        // URL:"/категория" - Отбражает первую страницу элементов указанной категории
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: null,
            url: "{genre}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Books", action = "List", page = 1 }
           );

        // URL:"/категория/PageX" - Отбражает заданную страницу элементов указанной категории
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: null,
            url: "{genre}/Page{page}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Books", action = "List" },
            constraints: new { page = @"\d+" }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: null,
            url: "Nav/Menu"
           );
```

маршруты для этого контроллера я не прописывал. подскажите как сделать универсальный маршрут для такого рода вызовов через форму?

Comment: Универсальный маршрут генерируется при создании нового проекта. Создайте новый проект и скопируйте из него :)

Comment: и куда его вставить в начало? тогда остальные неработают в конце не помогает

Comment: Вариантов немного, один вы попробовали - и он не подошел, попробуйте второй вариант :)

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: куда этот маршрут вставить? или скажите не универсальный а именно для этого метода действия

Comment: Подсказка: его не надо вставлять в начало!

Comment: Кстати, параметры по умолчанию я бы из него убрал.

Comment: в конец не работает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45968/discussion-between-aldmi-and-pavel-mayorov).

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{returnUrl}"
            );

Comment: вопрос открыт. если взялись помогать дак отвечайте тогда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Система маршрутизации всегда находит первое совпадение и использует его, остальные игнорируются. Какой из этого надо сделать вывод? - ну, например, что, если поставить первым более общий маршрут, то до более конкретного просто не дойдет, значит, **надо первыми определять наиболее конкретные роуты**.

В Вашем случае, первый роут достаточно общий, и его следовало бы опустить вниз. Универсальный (`routes.MapRoute( name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}");`) роут в любом случае надо ставить до первого, но если его (универсальный) поставить самым первым, он будет перехватывать некоторые другие (`"{genre}/Page{page}"`, например) - короче их двоих надо сдвинуть вниз, но универсальный должен быть выше, чем `""`

Есть еще возможность воспользоваться именованными роутами, но их лучше избегать

Comment: может Вы могли бы разъяснить почему *именованных роутов* лучше избегать?

Comment: @Bald, да, мог бы: потому что это нарушает принцип разделения ответственности. Когда Вы создаете ссылку в представлении - представление ничего не должно знать о каких-то там роутах, это создает лишние зависимости. Представьте, что этот роут в ходе разработки надо удалить/заменить - теперь Вам придется быть в дискомфорте: мало ли где во вьюшке он применяется? - это не то, чего хотели разработчики MVC

Comment: описанная Вами ситуация возможна и без *именованных роутов*: `Html.ActionLink("Метод", "Контроллер")` все в представлении *зашита* информация которая вызывает дискомфорт.

Comment: @Bald, тут уже никуда не денешься, но меньше зависимостей - лучше, если есть возможность - избегайте, с роутами такая возможность есть

Comment: мне кажется пояснение про именованные роуты лучше перенести в ответ. спасибо за разъяснения

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute( 
name: "Default", 
url: "{controller}/{action}" 
);
```

Такой маршрут работает. Заменил им последний маршрут.

```
   routes.MapRoute(
        name: null,
        url: "Nav/Menu"
       );
```